# Sql script - Incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I executed the following script, I am getting the following error. What should I do to correct this issue?

***Error***

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '@path'.
```

**Script**

```
GO
declare @path varchar(2000)
declare @path1 varchar(2000)
select @path=(SELECT [filename] FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE [name] LIKE 'master')
set @path= REPLACE(@path, 'master', 'test')
set @path1= REPLACE(@path, 'test.mdf', 'test_log.ldf')
select @path
select @path1
CREATE DATABASE [test] ON 
( FILENAME = @path ),
( FILENAME =N'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Comment: This attempts to read the location of the `master` database which does **not** have to be identical to the configured default data path (it's not on any of my machines, for instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
CREATE DATABASE [test] ON 
( FILENAME = @path ),
( FILENAME =N'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
```

with

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(400);
SET @sql = '
CREATE DATABASE [test] ON 
( FILENAME = ' + quotename(@path,'''') + ' ),
( FILENAME =N' + quotename(@path1,'''') + ' )
 FOR ATTACH
'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: My aim is to copy the mdf and ldf files to the sql server installation folder and then create the database. Is this the right way to do this? Should I make any changes in the script?

Comment: I would use the paths referenced in the article @marc_s linked to. Is this for a more "product-style" deployment where you're distributing DBs without knowing the server info ahead of time or is this for a more "internal-style" deployment where you need 1 process to deploy to dev/QA/UAT/prod?  Generally speaking the path to the master DB won't have any bogus (injected) values in it, but it's always a good idea to check values before concatenating & executing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not **really** reading the configured default data directory - you're just reading the directory where the `master` database is located (and that doesn't have to be the configured default directory for data files).

If you really want to know the real directory - you need to peek into the registry. See this [blog post here at SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Backup+/+Restore/71500/) for all the gory details...